# Python Pandas read_csv issue

Tags: python-2.7, csv, pandas

I have simple CSV file that looks like this:

```
inches,12,3,56,80,45
tempF,60,45,32,80,52
```

I read in the CSV using this command:

```
import pandas as pd
pd_obj = pd.read_csv('test_csv.csv', header=None, index_col=0)
```

Which results in this structure:

```
         1   2   3   4   5
0
inches  12   3  56  80  45
tempF   60  45  32  80  52
```

But I want this (unnamed index column):

```
         0   1   2   3   4
inches  12   3  56  80  45
tempF   60  45  32  80  52
```

**EDIT:** As @joris pointed out additional methods can be run on the resulting DataFrame to achieve the wanted structure.  My question is specifically about whether or not this structure could be achieved through `read_csv` arguments.

Comment: That 0 is the index name, you can just do `pd_obj.index.name = None` to remove it.

Comment: That results in my columns headers starting with 1 instead of 0.  Is there a way to not have the index column named when reading the CSV?

Comment: The index columns are named automatically with the numbers 0 -> number of columns - 1 as you specified to not read names from the CSV (`header=None`), and because col 0 is used as index, the actual columns start at 1. You can always do `pd_obj.columns = pd_obj.columns - 1`

Comment: Thanks @joris, I understand I can run two additional methods to get  the unnamed index columns I desire.  My question was regarding whether or not this could be achieved through `read_csv` arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the documentation of the function:

```
names : array-like
List of column names to use. If file contains no header row, then you
should explicitly pass header=None
```

so, apparently:

```
pd_obj = pd.read_csv('test_csv.csv', header=None, index_col=0, names=range(5))
```